# Create dynamic filterlist with PHP search them with JS

Tags: javascript, php, search, filter

can someone tell me how it's possible to create a dynamic filterlist with php and a searchbar which works with js? I have so far this code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Andere Inhalte</h1>
        
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<?php
foreach($workPlaceService->getAll() as $workPlace) {
        $id = $workPlace['id'];
?>  
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#"><?php echo $workPlace['uberschrift']; ?></a></li>
</ul>
        
<?php
}
?>
```

It shows the PHP results but I can't loop through them. Any help?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't loop through results because you create a lot of `ul`s on every iteration. Move `<ul id="myUL">` out of `foreach`:

```
<ul id="myUL">
<?php
foreach($workPlaceService->getAll() as $workPlace) {
        $id = $workPlace['id'];?>  
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $workPlace['uberschrift']; ?></a></li>
<?php
}?>
</ul>
```

Now you have one `ul#myUL` and iteration should work. Also don't forget to look at developers console for information about errors.